# Finding the weighted parameters of the vertex adjacency matrix for a derivative of azulene

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, density-functional-theory

In my last question ( [Numbering in a derivative of azulene](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/105036/numbering-in-a-derivative-of-azulene) ), I asked about the numbered of a molecule in order to find the Vertex Adjacency Matrix (VAM) of the same molecule. To explain my question properly, I will do my best to show my effort from A to Z as follows:
In general in order to find the VAM we use the formalism described by
[image: VAM formalism]
To apply it onto the molecule I am studying, I first applied it to azulene and with agreement with the paper [Quantum Interference, Graphs, Walks, and Polynomials](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/acs.chemrev.7b00733/suppl_file/cr7b00733_si_001.pdf) the VAM represented by A is:
[image: VAM for azulene only]

Now by having the correct numbering to my molecule ([Numbering in a derivative of azulene](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/105036/numbering-in-a-derivative-of-azulene)), it also should be a 10 x 10 matrix. The difference is instead of hydrogen we now have Oxygen and hydrogen Sulfide involved in positions 1,5 and 2,6 as shown:
[image: Finding the VAM for this molecule]

To find VAM the only way was to study the VAM of weighted Graphs as shown below:
[image: VAM for weighted graphs]

Here are my questions:
1- Should I include  the parameter h only for the weighted carbons since the numbering of the molecule I am studying includes only carbon?
2- If 1 is no, how should I include the k parameters described before hand?

Any other suggestions to find VAM is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a comment: The matrix-representation you search emerges from graph theory, and mathematics.  The numbers drawn in the structures earlier (1 for the carbonyl carbon, 2 to the carbon adjacent to the -SH group) a synthetic chemist refers to (e.g., "let us introduce an alkyl chain in the 4-position") do not (necessarily) relate to the numbers to denote the vertices in these nets.  These are [seasoned](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/253516227_Topological_Indices_Based_on_Topological_Distances_in_Molecular_Graph) descriptions are still [reviewed](http://euro-math-soc.eu/review/graph-theoretical-matrices-chemistry) ([2nd edition](https://www.crcpress.com/Graph-Theoretical-Matrices-in-Chemistry/Janezic-Milicevic-Nikolic-Trinajstic/p/book/9781138894280)), and [apparently](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0972860017301408)  the [Open Molecular Generator](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1758-2946-4-21) were one tool to generate them.

Comment: I have two questions: 1- Should I not have asked here and asked in the maths section? 
2- Would you be able to elaborate more from a chemist perspective on the relationship between numbers and vertices denotation?

Comment: @abedhaidar Re #1: It is not wrong to ask at ChemSE, or math; the question is at the interface between the two (like Chemometrics) or even a third (Cheminformatics).  I speculate contacting a not-only-pure-chemistry research group might be beneficial (e.g., Spackman, http://crystalexplorer.scb.uwa.edu.au/index.html; or even Hutchinson, https://hutchison.chem.pitt.edu/, because of his contributions to openbabel).  #2:  The numbering in the chemical structures follows the priniciple to spot a "parental" core structure, oriented on the canvas according to rules, and numbered according to others.

Comment: @abedhaidar (Part 2) Then, if there are chains, they are seen like decoration, with their own set of numbering (again a set of rules), eventually merged to the core structure while retaining their (inner) numbering.  Which is why an organic chemist would count 1 to 4 within the square (top most structure 3--6), once to 1 (for the branch 6--7, a methyl group), and once 1 to 2 (for the branch 3-2-1, an ethyl group) and say 1-ethyl-2-methyl-cyclobutane.  The matrix reminded me a bit to the connection tables seen e.g. in MDL's mol2 files (but, CT are not these matrices), that's all I can say here.